# How to find whether a mail is a draft or not?

Tags: jakarta-mail

How to check whether a mail is a draft or not from JavaMail API? I know that there is a Flag : DRAFT. But I connected to my gmail account and retrieved my Dfaft mails and checked whether DRAFT flag is true. But it always returns false. So it seems that's not a solution. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no guaranteed way.  Different email clients represent draft messages in different ways, usually by putting them in a folder named "Drafts" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

For Gmail, you'll want to use the special **gimap** JavaMail provider.  Then cast your `Message` objects to `GmailMessage`, call `GmailMessage.getLabels()`, and check the returned `String` array for the value `\Draft`:

```
    Arrays.asList(((GmailMessage) msg).getLabels()).contains("\\Draft")
```